# Using ASP MVC4 Simple membership with Linked in

Tags: entity-framework, oauth, asp.net-mvc-4

how would you best allow a person with a Linked in profile to create an account on your site using the new ASP MVC4 Simple membership, assuming that Oauth is the way to get the information.

Comment: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin Take the values they send in to register them with an MVC action after they've been authenticated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin

This is the basic idea around the authentication and then registering with the linkedin account details.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE
  authorize: true
</script>

<script type="IN/Login"> 
<form action="/register.html"> 
<p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>" /></p>
<p>Your Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="linkedin-id" value="<?js= id ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInAuth() {
  IN.API.Profile("me").result(function(me){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Account/Login', //Register as linkedin
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'Id': '" + me.values[0].id + "'}",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
    });
}
</script>
```